# correlate subquery in hive

Tags: subquery, hive

```
SELECT ndo.sku ParentSKU, visitsWhenSKUWasOnline.s
FROM 
Temp.NumberOfDaysOnline ndo 
JOIN
(
    SELECT SUM(gasessiondata.sessions) as s
    FROM gasessiondata
    WHERE
    gasessiondata.date >= ndo.FromDate
    AND
    gasessiondata.date <= ndo.ToDate
  ) as visitsWhenSKUWasOnline
  ON 1=1
```

I can't use `ndo.fromDate` and `ndo.ToDate` inside of the subquery since hive does not support correlated sub queries. What could be an alternative for something like this?

Edit:

down vote
favorite
I have a table like this:

```
date          val

2016-1-1       8
2016-2-1       10
2016-1-2       30
2016-1-3       30

Now, I have two dates coming in from a different table, let's call them `fromdate` and todate
```

If fromdate was 1, `2016-1-1` and Todate was `2016-1-2`, I need 8+30 = `38` as the final value

I need to check

`SUM(val)` of all those values dates corresponding to which are between the fromdate and twodate.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of you query is not often called "correlated subquery". A correlated subquery would be like this:

```
SELECT 
    ndo.sku AS ParentSKU, 
    (
        SELECT SUM(g.sessions)
        FROM gasessiondata AS g
        WHERE g.date >= ndo.FromDate
          AND g.date <= ndo.ToDate
    ) AS s
FROM 
    Temp.NumberOfDaysOnline AS ndo ;
```

Your query is similar to a `LATERAL` join (`CROSS / OUTER APPLY` in SQL Server). This type of correlated joins has not been implemented in many DBMS.

It's easy to rewrite though so the join is done first and then the `GROUP BY`. This simple query should be supported by most, if not all DBMS:

```
SELECT 
    ndo.sku AS ParentSKU, 
    SUM(g.sessions) AS s
FROM 
        Temp.NumberOfDaysOnline AS ndo 
    JOIN
        gasessiondata AS g
    ON  g.date >= ndo.FromDate
    AND g.date <= ndo.ToDate
GROUP BY 
    ndo.PK,             -- the PRIMARY KEY of the table
    ndo.sku ;           -- and any column used in the SELECT list
```

Seems that Hive supports only equi-joins and cross joins. Moving the condition to the `WHERE` clause might solve this:

```
SELECT 
    ndo.sku AS ParentSKU, 
    SUM(g.sessions) AS s
FROM 
        Temp.NumberOfDaysOnline AS ndo 
    CROSS JOIN
        gasessiondata AS g
WHERE 
        g.date >= ndo.FromDate
    AND g.date <= ndo.ToDate
GROUP BY 
    ndo.PK,             -- the PRIMARY KEY of the table
    ndo.sku ;           -- and any column used in the SELECT list
```